# "undefined is not a function" ao chamar "tabs"

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Estou com um erro na minha função JS, quando vejo pelo browser, mostra a seguinte mensagem:

> undefined is not a function

Por favor alguma dica a respeito desse erro?

```
<link rel="stylesheet"    href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

<script>
  $(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs();// undefined is not a function 
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Já verificou se o js do plugin foi adicionado e está carregando normalmente?

Comment: Qual plugin você está utilizando? Faltam alguns dados para que possamos responder sua pergunta...

Comment: Você está a seleccionar o elemento correctamente? Verifique se existe um elemento com o ID igual a "tabs".

Comment: Adicionei os scripts do mesmo jeito que estava  no Demo do Jquery.

Comment: Boa tarde, alguma das respostas lhe resolveu o problema? Se sim por favor marque-a como "Correta". Se não diga o que falta. Grato.

Answer (score 1):

Suponho que você esteja usando o protocolo [`FILE`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) ao invés de um servidor HTTP em sua máquina.

O uso do protocolo abreviado `//` só funciona se a página for carregada em `HTTP`. Em páginas com protocolo [`FILE`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) o `//` é interpretado no Windows por exemplo como `D:` ou `C:` (ou melhor dizendo o `//` acessa a pasta raiz), ao invés de puxar do servidor CDN do Jquery os arquivos o navegador irá tentar puxar da sua máquina local.

O preferencial para desenvolver na sua máquina é usar um servidor HTTP como:

- [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi)
- [Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/download.html)
- [Lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/download/)
- Se for usar PHP você pode baixar o [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/), que já possui Apache.

> Leia sobre o protocolo HTTP: http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol

Portanto ao usar o Apache (por exemplo) com `<link href="//...">` o navegador irá interpretar o `//` como `http` ou `https`.

A vantagem de usar `//` é que a sua página for [`HTTPS`](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) (http com certificado de segurança), não haverá "bloqueios de segurança" ou "mensagens de erro" (claro que o CDN que você usa, terá que ter suporte para [`SSL` ou `TLS`](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security)).

Porém se você tem certeza que você não vai usar `https` em seu site, então use o `http` sem "abreviação" ou você quiser mesmo desenvolver em [`FILE`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme):

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Você deve ter esquecido de carregar o código do plugin. Quando tentar chamar a propriedade `.tabs`, o valor dela será `undefined` e os parênteses irão tentar invocá-la como um função, gerando o erro.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo o problema é o caminho dos plugins, abaixo esta o correto

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```